# .net regasm question

Tags: .net, com, regasm

Lets say we have this scenario a setup that deploys a .net com dll and runs regasm on it, this setup has no uninstall so unregister Will never be called.. And you can run the setup over and over again..

Is there any danger in doing so?? What would happen if i deploy à new setup with à new version of the dll..

Is there any danger in never running uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure here, but I believe if you keep all of the the IIDs, ClassIDs and ProgIDs the same, you're OK.  If you keep generating new unique IDs for your classes, you could clutter up the registry with unused entries.  So it's probably best to have a good, explicit handle on all of your COM IDs when you deploy something like this.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is number one reason for having ComVisible(false) at the assembly level and explicit ComVisible(true) at each entity you want to expose and explicitly specifying GUIDs for each entity to expose. Otherwise registry COM hell comes sooner then you would like it to.